# Not able to debug Javascript code for my assignment

Tags: javascript, html, debugging, web

I'm not able to debug my code, please help me

github folder [link](https://github.com/yashasvinks/coursera-test/tree/master/module4-solution).

github pages [link](https://yashasvinks.github.io/coursera-test/module4-solution/).
the description of the project:
loop over an array of names and print out either a hello or goodbye to that name to the **browser** `console`. If the name starts with a letter j or J, you are to print out Goodbye JSomeName. If the name starts with any other letter, you are to print out Hello SomeName.

Answer (score 0):

I have cloned your Repo and reviewed your Code. I have made some corrections to your code.

Please refer to the below codes to get the correct result.

Wrong way of linking JS file.

> index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="js/script.js"></script>
    <script src="js/SpeakHello.js"></script>
    <script src="js/SpeakGoodbye.js"></script>
  </head>
</html>
```

The correct way of linking your JS file (You need to change as suggested below) in your index.html file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script src="js/SpeakHello.js"></script>
  <script src="js/SpeakGoodbye.js"></script>
  <script src="js/script.js"></script>
</head>
<body></body>
</html>
```

You just want to access the name argument that is passed in, which you do with just name, not helloSpeaker.name.

Make below changes in your script.js file

```
(function() {
  var names = ["Yaakov", "John", "Jen", "Jason", "Paul", "Frank", "Larry", "Paula", "Laura", "Jim"];
  for (var i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
    var firstLetter = names[i].charAt(0).toLowerCase();
    if (firstLetter === 'j') {
      byeSpeaker.speak(names[i]);
    } 
    else {
      helloSpeaker.speak(names[i]);
    }
  }
})();
```

Make below changes in your SpeakerHello.js

```
(function(window) {
  var helloSpeaker = {};
  helloSpeaker.speak = function(name) {
    console.log(speakWord + " " + name);
  }
  var speakWord = "Hello";
  window.helloSpeaker = helloSpeaker;
}(window));
```

Make below changes in your SpeakerGoodBye.js

```
(function(window) {
  var byeSpeaker = {};
    byeSpeaker.speak = function() {
        console.log(speakWord + " " + name);
    }
    var speakWord = "Good Bye";
    window.byeSpeaker = byeSpeaker;
    }(window));
```

Answer (score -1):

your **speakGoodBye.js** file

```
(function(window) {
  var speakWord = "Good Bye";
  var byeSpeaker={}// <== add this
  byeSpeaker.speak = function(name) {
    console.log(speakWord + " " + name);
  }
    window.byeSpeaker = byeSpeaker;
})(window);
```

caus you'r calling object from
**script.js** file

```
helloSpeaker.speak(names[i]);
```